# Get all the entries drawn on particular X-axis in MP Android Line chart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

[image]

What I am trying to achieve is that in the graph we plotted multiple entries for x-axis value 28. If user clicks on any of the values which are falling on 28 in X-axis by that I need to grab other values also for the same 28 of x-axis.

Comment: do you want to show all values of y in marker view ?

Comment: Yes Exactly.I want to show all values on Markerview.

Comment: can you please share your code ?

Comment: On refreshcontent method I'm doing like this  @Override
    public void refreshContent(Entry e, Highlight highlight) {
        tvContent.setText("" + e.getX()); // set the entry-value as the display text
        //highlight.
        super.refreshContent(e, highlight);
    }

Comment: But the thing is that you click on the point it will give you the position of y at that specific point we dont have all entries there. So the only thing we had is single entry with x and y values.

Comment: How you are getting values of x and y just by calling e.getX() ?

Comment: e.getx() and e.gety() to get the respective values at the particular entry click.Now I want to know how can I get all the Y-axis values plotted against the particular Xaxis.